# How to show all Records between two dates (VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a `Form` and a Local database and `Table1` in `DataGridView`. Also I have 2 `DatetimePickers` and a button.

[image]

The `Date` column is defined as `DateTime` datatype.

How to show the records between two dates in `DataGridView` by pressing `button1`?

I would like to do this with `DataGridView Task` --> `Add Query...` --> `Query Builder...`

If this is not simple, any solution is welcome.

Answer (score 3):

**Here is a solution (by me and Google searching).**

**This is simple way.**

In `DataGridView` --> `Add Query...` --> `Query Builder..`.
In `Date` column (or whatever you have) in `Filter` cell write: BETWEEN @Date1 AND @Date2.
Click OK and again click OK.

In `Form` area you see now a new line under Form title area with 2 text boxes. First is `Date1` and second is `Date2`. After text boxes area is a button named `Fillby`.
Change the name of Date1, Date2 and Fillby from properties to whatever you like e.g. From:- To: - Search.

**An other way to do this is more difficult.**

First put 2 `buttons` and 2 `Timepickers`  in `Form` area.

Next in `DataGridView` --> `Add Query...` --> `Query Builder..`.
In `Date` column (or whatever you have) in `Filter` cell write: BETWEEN @Date1 AND @Date2.
Click OK and again click OK.

In Code View area of `Form` paste this code for first Button (Button1):

```
Public Function GetFromDate(ByVal value As DateTime) As DateTime
        Return New DateTime(value.Year, value.Month, value.Day, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    End Function

    Public Function GetToDate(ByVal value As DateTime) As DateTime
        Return New DateTime(value.Year, value.Month, value.Day, 23, 59, 59, 999)
    End Function

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim BeginningDateTime As Date = GetFromDate(DateTimePicker1.Value)
        Dim EndingDateTime As Date = GetToDate(DateTimePicker2.Value)
        Try
            Me.Table2TableAdapter.FillBy(Me.Database1DataSet1.Table2, New System.Nullable(Of Date)(CType(BeginningDateTime, Date)), New System.Nullable(Of Date)(CType(EndingDateTime, Date)))
     Catch ex As System.Exception
         System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
     End Try
    End Sub
```

And next this code for second Button (Button2):

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Me.Table2TableAdapter.Fill(Me.Database1DataSet1.Table2)
    End Sub
```

You have to Change:

1) `Table2TableAdapter` in what is your Table Adapter.

2) `Database1DataSet1` in what is your Database DataSet.

3) `Table2` in what is your Table.

The code `FillBy` , `DateTimePicker1` , `DateTimePicker2` must change if you have difference in your database.

For more formations of your code you can see the code from your Query Builder.
It looks like:

```
Private Sub FillByToolStripButton_Click...
```

There you can find all info's to change the code above.

After all you can delete this code (`Private Sub FillByToolStripButton_Click...`).

That's all i have found and i solve my problem for searching between two dates.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and easiest method...

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

```
    'Filter the Connections Date wise
    Me.TblUserBindingSource.Filter = "doj >= '" & DateTimePicker1.Value & "' and doj <= '" & DateTimePicker2.Value & "'"
```

end sub